# Send email using ajax or javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I need to send email along with subject and message.I went through many blogs,but most of them used ajax and PHP. Is there any means to send mail only using ajax or JavaScript alone???I don't want to use mailto in html..IF there is any other means to do please help me!!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you count Node.js, or just client-side?

Comment: Node.Js won't be a problem!!All i want is that i don't want to use PHP,rest anything will do!!But i don't have much info about node.js

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var link = "mailto:me@example.com"
         + "?cc=myCCaddress@example.com"
         + "&subject=" + escape("This is my subject")
         + "&body=" + escape("This is body")
;

window.location.href = link;
```

You can use [this library](https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782) for making ajax calls to send emails.

**Updated-C# code for sending mails:**

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.MyWebsiteDomainName.com", 25);

smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@MyWebsiteDomainName.com", "myIDPassword");
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();


        //Setting From , To and CC
        mail.From = new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName", "MyWeb Site");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@MyWebsiteDomainName"));
        mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("MyEmailID@gmail.com"));


 smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Well then..i don't want to use php...how to send email using c#??

Comment: @AshishKumar:you need to 
register for Mandrill to get an API key

Comment: do i need to paste this code within my ashx page and pass data from html page through ajax??

Comment: Yes in the ashx.cs file which handles send request.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is of course client based so doesn't have the capabilities as say C# or PHP on the server. To send email, without calling some server-side code, you are basically limited to mailto option only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any possibility to send mail from javascript without using your local mail client and mailto except using third party apis:

Here is a tutorial that uses Ajax to send mails but you have to get a mandrill api key first:

https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782

Comment: its the same link as the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

For sending email you required some smtp server as JavaScript is client script language

Answer (score 0):

[Nodemailer](http://www.nodemailer.com/) looks like a nice Node.js mailing library. I didn't test it though.